# How to Parse big json file with Golang

Tags: go

I have a big json file (larger than 1.8 GB), this file is generated each day by another go application. I want to process this file as fast as I can with Golang.
What would the best solution here?

json structure within file is like following

```
[
  {
    "attribute_id": 123,
    "attribute_name": "....",
    "date":"2022-07-01 00:03:02"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: It has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42612995/10781026

Comment: Search for a streaming solution